# npm run eject error?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

This error occurs after I run `npm run eject` in my react project.

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem (error in image description).

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: As the error message says `Remove any untracked files`.

Answer (score 5):

make sure you commit all your code before you run that

Answer (score 0):

Before you eject, you need to make sure that git sees no changes in your files. Either commit or reset the branch

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have git error, It takes whole repository. In order to avoid this error initialise git repository by git init and them git add. followed by git commit -m "meesage"

Answer (score -1):

before you run your commit, `npm run eject` you should to upload the project into

```
git. it should be needed to.....
git add .
git commit -am "save and then eject"
```

and after completing this try again....

```
npm run eject
```