# React Native NPM run eject error Visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying these days to run a react native project following the steps by a tutorial. Everything was running okay until when I ran this command like the man of the  [video](https://youtu.be/6ZnfsJ6mM5c?t=449) does:

```
npm run eject
```

But I have this error:

[image]

I checked the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49695449/npm-run-eject-error#_=_) but only half the errors disappeared using their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the package.json file and make sure there should be a script.

```
"eject": "expo eject"
```

Actually, when we use the expo-cli so we don't need to be the concern with the native code. But sometimes we need to integrate the third party libraries which uses the react-native link cmd for linking or sometimes we need to write own native code so in that situation we need the native code.

we can use the expo eject or npm run eject cmd to get the native code for the project.

**Note:** If you are using the react-native-cli so you don't need eject.

Comment: before use run eject i have this http://prntscr.com/m3d26c. If i press 'a' it runs to my simulator and my visual studio code view is like this http://prntscr.com/m3d30z .But if i dont and i run ''npm run eject" command ,my visual studio code view is like this : http://prntscr.com/m3d3gj .As you can see,there are some extra files like android and ios... does that mean something? does the second one way with "run eject" command has more capabilities?

Comment: yes, expo downloads the native code for you by running "expo eject".
for more information please read this https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject